# Resize image so that it fits JPanel grid

Tags: java, image, swing, resize

I have a JPanel with grid layout of (5 , 7 ) , 5 rows , 7 columns.

When i try to add images to a grid panel

```
    Img = new ImageIcon("ImagePath");
    JLabel Label = new JLabel(Img);
    add(picLabel);
```

It appears the image is too large for my grid panel , and only a small portion of the image is shown on the grid panel.

**How do i add an image to the grid so that the images resizes to the grid size.???**

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a JLabel and ImageIcon. Instead, I'd

- Create a class that extends JPanel
- Override its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method
- Remember to call the super's method in my override
- Give it a BufferedImage field, say called image
- Pass the image into the class via a constructor or setter parameter, or both.
- Call the `g.drawImage(image,....)` overload that allows for re-sizing of the image so that it fills the JPanel.

Links:

- [Graphics API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

Check out this overload:

```
public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img,
            int x,
            int y,
            int width,
            int height,
            ImageObserver observer)
```

or this one:

```
public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img,
            int dx1,
            int dy1,
            int dx2,
            int dy2,
            int sx1,
            int sy1,
            int sx2,
            int sy2,
            ImageObserver observer)
```

---

**Edit**
For example,

```
// big warning: code not compiled nor tested
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
  private BufferedImage image;

  public ImagePanel(BufferedImage image) {
    this.image = image;
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (image != null) {
      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do i override in the paintComponent ??

Comment: @Computernerd: Your question confuses me as I'm not sure what you mean. You override the method, make sure to call the super method, and then use the Graphics object supplied to draw your image. Please check out the [Performing Custom Painting with Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: @Computernerd: for example, please see edit to answer. Note that code has not been tested.

Comment: I am getting a "Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match" error when i use image = ImageIO.read(filepath)

Answer (score 2):

> How do i add an image to the grid so that the images resizes to the grid size.???

Check out Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/).

It will dynamically resize itself to fill the space available to the label.

Then the Icon can be used an on component that takes an Icon without custom painting.